# Duda respecto a "=new Image"

Tags: javascript, poo

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, la duda que tengo es la siguiente,

¿Que ocurre cuando se escribe el código de esta forma? (fondo.imagen = new Image();) 
-¿Por que "new Image"? 
-¿Qué ocurre con el "Image" original?

Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El objeto sigue existiendo pero sin referencia a el desde esa variable. Si no hay mas referencias a el cuando actuel el garbage colector se deberia eliminar.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir como texto y no como imagen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo primero que te recomendaría, es que leas un poco sobre como funciona el lenguaje, y sobre teoría de objetos (no POO, acá no hay de eso).

Js es medio complicado para algunas cosas, y mezcla conceptos sin dejar en claro de donde vienen las cosas.

No hay un `IMAGE` anterior. Simplemente, porque `IMAGE` en ese ámbito es un objeto y se lo estas aplicando a `fondo.imagen`.

Esa linea lo que dice es:

En `fondo.imagen`, pone un objeto nuevo del tipo `IMAGE`.

Eso no quiere decir que destruye `IMAGE` o que hace otra cosa, lo que hace es pasarle una referencia a un objeto nuevo (creado recien, con el `new`) a esa propiedad de ese objeto que vos le decis.

Puede sonar complicado, y lo es si no tenes conocimientos de como funcionan los objetos.